# How can I configure Emacs to use Ubuntu's disappearing scrollbars?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, scrollbar, ubuntu-unity

Ubuntu 14.04 has these pretty overlay scrollbars that hide when unused.

Is there a way to configure Emacs to use this kind of scrollbar when run in windowed (GUI) mode?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How do Emacs scroll bars look like?  Normally, Emacs should use the scroll bars from the underlying toolkit.

Comment: @lunaryorn You are correct. Hmm, seems like Unity offers two scrollbar styles, the thin one for gEdit and gnome-terminal, and a thicker one for Web browsers and Emacs.

Comment: Are you trying to make changes to the Emacs code? If you are just trying to change the configuration settings without changing the code, then you should ask on SuperUser.com, ubuntu.stackexchange.com, or unix.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is only for programming questions.